# Change of variable formulas in discrete calculus?

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, difference-equations, finite-differences

Crossposted from [MSE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721350/changing-variables-in-discrete-calculus)

In discrete calculus one defines the $h$-difference operator $$\Delta_h[f(x)] = f(x+h) - f(x)$$
and we often define $\Delta = \Delta_1.$ We can similarly define the [indefinite sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum) $\Delta_h^{-1}$ and set $\Delta^{-1} = \Delta_1^{-1}.$

Most books on discrete calculus only include results for $h=1.$
For example, the above link gives that
$$\Delta^{-1}\sin rx = \frac{-\cos(r[x-\frac{1}{2}])}{2\sin\frac{r}{2}}$$

Through an ugly computation I managed to work out that $$\Delta_h^{-1}[\sin rx] = \frac{-\cos(r[x-\frac{h}{2}])}{2\sin\frac{rh}{2}}$$

What I'd like is a uniform procedure for recovering the "$h$-version" from such results. How could I have derived (or even just guessed) the second formula from the first? Is there something like the change of variable formula in calculus? Maybe some version of the 'dimensional analysis' heuristics in ordinary calculus that tells you where to insert the $h$'s? As a test, given a formula at random from the previous link like $\Delta[\log x] = \log(1 + \frac{1}{x})$ I'd like to be able to see immediately that $\Delta_h[\log x] = \log(1 + \frac{h}{x})$ without carrying out the actual calculation.

A search trough the standard references didn't turn up much, so any help or references would be welcome.

Comment: Dimensional analysis, as you mention, would seem to be exactly what you need. In your test, the argument of a log has to be dimensionless. Any length $x$ has to be given in units of your scale $h$ in order to be quantified in a dimensionless manner. Hence, $x \rightarrow x/h$.

Comment: I saw that, but couldn't see how to make it work for other examples e.g. for $\Delta_h^{-1}x^a,$ or $\Delta_h^{-1}b^x$

Comment: Also, isn't the argument in $\log x$ already necessarily dimensionless?

Comment: If you know $\Delta_1^{-1}f(rx)$ you can obtain $\Delta_h^{-1}f(rx)$ by rescaling $r\mapsto rh$ and $x\mapsto x/h$. To obtain such functional inverses of the derivative operator it is easiest to transform to Fourier space, I worked this out in the answer box.

Comment: @Kariuki - The answers now given treat the issue in much more detail, but just to respond to your query in comments, also on the left hand side, it should really be $\log (x/h)$; but then the extra constant $-\log h$ is canceled once you apply the difference operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of the differential operator $\partial_x\equiv d/dx$ one has $f(x+h)=e^{h\partial_x}f(x)$, hence
$$\Delta_h=e^{h\partial_x}-1.$$
Upon Fourier transformation, $\hat{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}f(x)\,dx$, one has $\partial_x\mapsto -ik$, hence
$$\hat{\Delta}_h=e^{-ihk}-1\Leftrightarrow \hat{\Delta}_h^{-1}=\frac{e^{ihk}}{1-e^{ihk}}.$$

In this way you can calculate, for any function $f(x)$ with Fourier transform $\hat{f}(k)$:
$$\Delta_h^{-1}f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{i(h-x)k}}{1-e^{ihk}}\hat{f}(k)\,\frac{dk}{2\pi}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_h(x'-x)f(x')\,dx'$$
with [Dirac-delta-function](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=dirac+delta+function&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) kernel
$$F_h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{i(h+x)k}}{1-e^{ihk}}\,\frac{dk}{2\pi}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\delta(x+nh).$$
The relation $F_h(x)=(1/h)F_1(x/h)$ gives the scaling with $h$ requested by the OP:

> $\Delta_h^{-1}f(x)$ follows from  $\Delta_1^{-1}f(rx)$ by rescaling
> $r\mapsto rh$ and $x\mapsto x/h$.

---

The "test cases" mentioned by the OP include: $\Delta_1^{-1}\log rx=x\log r+\log \Gamma(x)$, hence
$$\Delta_h^{-1}\log rx=(x/h)\log(rh)+\log\Gamma(x/h).$$
Similarly, $\Delta_1^{-1}a^{rx}=a^{rx}/(a^r-1)$, hence
$$\Delta_h^{-1} a^{rx}=a^{rx}/(a^{rh}-1),$$
and $\Delta_1^{-1}(rx)^a=r^aB_{a+1}(x)/(a+1)$, hence
$$\Delta_h^{-1}(rx)^a=(rh)^aB_{a+1}(x/h)/(a+1).$$

Comment: For what functions $f$ will these manipulations work? Also, what is the meaning of the clearly divergent integral in the definition of $F_h(x)$?

Comment: But you do use $F_h$ in your derivation of the rule.

Comment: Even though $F_h$ is not needed in the use of the rule, this not clearly defined function $F_h$ **is** used in your **derivation** of the rule. Also, again, it is unclear for what functions $f$ your derivation would hold.

Comment: $F_h$ is a sum of Dirac delta functions.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\De\Delta$Elementarily: The relation $f=\De_h^{-1}g$ means that $f(x+h)-f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

For a function $g$ and each real $r$, we know $f_r:=\De_1^{-1}g_r$, where $g_r(x):=g(rx)$, so that
$$f_r(x+1)-f_r(x)=g(rx) \tag{10}\label{10}$$

For real $h\ne0$, real $r$, and all real $x$, let now
$$f_{r,h}(x):=f_{rh}(x/h). \tag{20}\label{20}$$
Then
$$f_{r,h}(x+h)-f_{r,h}(x)=f_{rh}(x/h+1)-f_{rh}(x/h)=g((rh)(x/h))=g(rx)$$
for all real $x$. That is, $f_{r,h}=\De_h^{-1}g_r$. $\quad\Box$

---

Note that we do not need or impose any conditions on the functions $g$ and $f_r$ (such as measurability, continuity, growth, etc.) except for \eqref{10}.

---

To illustrate these simple considerations, consider the example from your post, with $g_r(x)=\sin rx$ and $f_r(x)=\dfrac{-\cos(r(x-1/2))}{2\sin(r/2)}$. Then, by \eqref{20}, for $\De_h^{-1}g_r=f_{r,h}$ we have
$$(\De_h^{-1}g_r)(x)=f_{r,h}(x)=\dfrac{-\cos((rh)(x/h-1/2))}{2\sin(rh/2)}
=\dfrac{-\cos(r(x-h/2))}{2\sin(rh/2)}. \quad\Box$$

Comment: Thank you! I've accepted Carlo's answer as he gave the explicit rescaling procedure first, but I much prefer your derivation.